# Numpy return sub-array with minimal sum

Tags: numpy

Given a 2D numpy array, e.g. `np.array([[1,1,0], [1,2,0], [0,0,4]])`, I want to return the sub-array with the minimal sum.

In this case, this would be the array `np.array([1,1,0])`.

How can I achieve this, ideally only using built-in numpy functions? It seems numpy does not allow specifying a key function, unlike vanilla python.

Comment: Sum with the axis argument so that you sum along the rows, then find the argmin of that, which will give you the row index into the original array with the minimum sum.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First we can use the build in function `numpy.sum` and get sums allong axis 1. How a numpy array is indexed can be found [here](https://numpy.org/devdocs/user/absolute_beginners.html#basic-array-operations).

```
    array = np.array([[1,1,0], [1,2,0], [0,0,4]])
    internal_sums = np.sum(array, axis=1)
```

Now we have all the sums stored in the variable 'internal_sums'. Next we use the numpy function 'numpy.argmin' to get the index of the minimal sum.

```
    minsum_index = np.argmin(internal_sums)
```

Now we simply get the array at the correct index

```
    minsum_array = array[minsum_index]
```

Comment: Thank you!

Despite being longer than min(array, key=sum), it is actually much faster using numpy, just as I hoped.

Speed for 10,000 executions:

Python: 1.03177 seconds
Numpy: 0.05466 seconds

Answer (score 2):

To add on to the excellent answer above, you can also use the ndarray methods, which lets you squeeze it all into one line!

```
array = np.array([[1,1,0], [1,2,0], [0,0,4]])
min_array = array[array.sum(1).argmin()]
```